# Iterate over all elements of FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I get an array (or object) of all of the elements in a `FlatList` inside my component? I would like to iterate over this list of elements in order to give each of them a new prop programmatically.

Here is my `FlatList` inside my `Menu` component:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.SubMenuData} keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title} renderItem={({item}) => 
    <SubMenuItem style={IsolationStyles.Hide} data={item} parent={this}/>
}/>
```

From a method, `Focus()` in my `Menu` component I want to do something like this pseudo-code:

```
Focus(){
    var SubMenuItems = FlatListRef.getChildren()
    for(let item of SubMenuItems){
        item.setProp('type','type2');
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this?

Comment: Thanks. Could you not do `<FlatList data={this.state.SubMenuData.map(obj => ({...obj, type: 'type2' })} ... />`, i.e. change the data before you pass it to the `FlatList`?

Comment: No sorry, this prop needs to be added dynamically

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to say is that you have the data in state already. Why do you need something like `FlatListRef.getChildren()`? You can manipulate `this.state.SubMenuData` with `setState` however you like.